# Read files from a folder on the server

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to load images from a folder on the server. However, I saved the images without extension. so I want to load the images and add ".jpg" to each image but it's not working. Here's my code, I'm not sure how to sort it out.

```
<?php
// READ FILES FROM THE GALLERY FOLDER
    $choice = $_POST['folder'];
    $dir = ( dirname( dirname ( __DIR__  ))) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Images" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "$choice" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$extension = ".jpg";
    $images = glob($dir . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE).$extension;

// DRAW HTML ?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Very Simple PHP gallery</title>
     <link href="1-basic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
 <body>
 <!-- [THE GALLERY] -->
   <div id="gallery"><?php
     foreach ($images as $i) {
     printf("<img src='../../Images/$choice/%s'/>", basename($i));
     echo basename($i);
}
?></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your images are saved without an extension, why are you trying to add one when loading them?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ya i know. it's silly. but I save the images without extension cause I have an app that downloads them and adds the extension to them. I'm trying to make a web page that I can load up the folder and see what Images are there.

Comment: I can't see where you add `.jpg` in your code.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte edited.

Comment: But if you want to view your images when they still have no extension, then you just reference them as-is, without the extension.

Comment: @PatrickQ I tried. but they wont load up without extension. If I add images with extension it works just fine.

Comment: Why not rename every image and actually add an extension?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte My app doesn't read the images if they have an extension (I have to amend the app but I cannot for the time being). so I'm looking for a workaround atm. Is there a way I can rename the images as tmp without actually saving the new name?

Comment: I actually made it work... changed this     $images = glob($dir . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE).$extension; to     $images = glob($dir . "*", GLOB_BRACE).$extension;

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Changed this

```
$images = glob($dir . "*.*", GLOB_BRACE);
```

To

```
$images = glob($dir . "*", GLOB_BRACE);
```